# Solving a dual integral equations with higher-order Bessel functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, boundary-value-problem, bessel-functions

Consider the following dual integral equations which has been obtained while solving a mixed boundary value problem:
$$
\int_0^\infty \psi_k(\lambda) J_k (\lambda r) \mathrm{d}\lambda =
F(r) \delta_{1k} \qquad (0 < r < R) 
$$

$$
\int_0^\infty \lambda \psi_k(\lambda) J_k (\lambda r) \mathrm{d}\lambda = 0 \qquad (r>R)
$$ 
where $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\psi_k(\lambda)$ are the unknown functions.
In addition, $F(r)$ is a known (radial) function.

The solution for $k=1$ can readily be obtained following the standard recipes by Sneddon.
Accordingly, the order of Bessel function can be reduced to zero by multiplying by $r$ and differentiating by $r$ to obtain $(k=1)$
$$
\int_0^\infty \lambda \psi_1(\lambda) J_0 (\lambda r) \mathrm{d}\lambda =
\frac{1}{r} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} r} \left( rF(r) \right) 0 := G(r) \qquad (0 < r < R) 
$$

$$
\int_0^\infty \lambda^2 \psi_1(\lambda) J_0 (\lambda r) \mathrm{d}\lambda = 0 \qquad (r>R)
$$

By making use of the identity
$$
\int_0^\infty J_0(\lambda r) \sin(\lambda t) \mathrm{d}\lambda = 
\frac{H(t-r)}{\left(t^2-r^2\right)^{1/2}}
$$
a solution of the outer problem above $(r>R)$ can be chosen of the form
$$
\psi_1(\lambda) = \frac{1}{\lambda^2} 
\int_0^R \chi_1 (t) \sin(\lambda t) \mathrm{d} t
$$
where $\chi_1(t)$ is now the new unknown function. 
Upon substitution of this solution into the inner problem equation, the problem can eventually be transformed into a Fredholm integral.

> > > My question is:
> >
> > For $k \ne 1$, $\psi_k(\lambda) = 0$ are trivial solutions of the problem.
> >     Are these unique solutions or other solutions also can exist?

Any help or advice would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.